# Model selection by LR test: How to interpret the results?

Tags: model-selection, stata, likelihood-ratio

I'm using lrtest to compare two models in Stata. When I get a p-value is 0.7673 that is greater than 0.05, does it mean model3 is better than the other model1? I wanted to learn how to interpret which model is better?

Results:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Without more detail about the models this might be rather hard to answer conclusively.

Answer (score 2):

The high p-value indicates that the data is consistent with the claim that the extra variables together (not just individually) do not substantially improve model fit.

On the other hand, 189 observations with 12 covariates is not a whole lot of data. That's arguably a lot of parameters for this amount of data, so an improvement may not be detectable (as opposed to not there).